# For Statement and Img Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I am using the following logic in a for statement

The problem I am having is that it seems that when you hover over the first image - it hides 'all the images'. I want to try and preserve the `[i]` for each image but it seems it doesn't do this ?

```
function myHandler(elem, img) {
  var curImg = img;
  var curImgId = curImg.find('img');

  $(curImgId).live('click', function() {
          $(this).hide();
  });   

//Other stuff requiring preservation of [i]
}
```

Comment: What should happen when you hover over the image?

Comment: well it should hide the individual image. i.e. the first image should ONLY hide - instead it hides every other image ? same with 2nd, 3rd etc

Comment: Does it have to hide, or is setting the css visibility property okay for you? http://jsfiddle.net/njPdQ/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hover over the first image, that image hides. This is normal.

However, your problem is the second image moves into the space previously filled by the first image, and the second image gets a mouse event, which causes that image to hide. This happens continuously until the rest of the images all disappear.

You can test this by hovering over the second image - all the images to the right disappear.

Comment: yeah but it wouldn't matter its hide or something else - the problem seems to relate to closures and the preservation of `[i]` ? i.e. change the method to `click`

Comment: @John B You can test my answer with this: http://jsfiddle.net/njPdQ/4/ . Look at the console after mousing over each image.

Comment: sure but now change it to `$(curImgId).live('click', function() {` to see what i'm talking about ? - see http://jsfiddle.net/njPdQ/5/

Comment: @John B When you click on the `<img>`, the iframe is navigated to the href of the `<a>`. Add `return false` to the end of the handler to stop that: http://jsfiddle.net/njPdQ/7/

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I would second @Digital Planes answer,
the second image comes in place of first one due to first one being hidden and triggers an event.
Here is a working code : http://jsfiddle.net/njPdQ/8/

The change is :

function myHandler(elem, img) {

```
console.log(elem);

var curImg = img;
var curImgId = curImg.find('img');
console.log(img);
$(curImgId).live('mouseenter', function() {
    console.log("Event handler: Hiding " + elem);
   // $(this).hide();    
    $(this).css("visibility", "hidden"); //this will keep the images in place

});
```

}

Comment: yeah I suspected something like this. Any chance you can help out with some code ? :)

Comment: Yes sure, give me few minutes.